# How to read fixed length character using BufferReader or other method?

Tags: java, string, unicode, byte

If I use BufferReader to read a line, I can get a string of a line.
The code is this :

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("E:\\tmp\\aaa.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));


String line = null;  
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
    System.out.println(line.length() + " " +line.substring(0, 2);
}
```

The contents of aaa.txt is :

```
一二三四1234
```

so. the result of running the code is :

```
8 一二
```

From the result , I know the length of a chinese character in String is one, not two.

**So If I use line.substring(0,2), I get two chinese character "一二". 
But I hope that, the result of  line.substring(0,2) is "一".**

I mean that, in my eye the length of "一二三四1234" is 12, not 8.I can use substring(0,2) to 
extract fixed length character.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure about this "the length of "一二三四1234" is 12, not 8" ?

Comment: Why would you expect `substring(0, 2)` to give you *one* character? You're asking for 2! Are you getting confused between the number of *bytes* used to represent the characters, and the characters themselves? Also, you're currently using the default character encoding - are you sure that's appropriate?

Comment: The "length" of a Chinese character are usually 1 (sometimes 2, if beyond Basic Multilingual Plane for rare characters). I think you might be referring to the byte representation of the string, which is abstracted away at the `Reader` level (character stream).

Answer (score 1):

> From the result , I know the length of a chinese character in String is one, not two.

Thats right so every sign is a char, so the length of these "一二三四1234" string is 8

so why 12?

> I mean that, in my eye the length of "一二三四1234" is 12, not 8.I can use substring(0,2) to extract fixed length character.

if you know the index of the char you want you can use the code below instead:

```
String s = "一二三四1234";
char c = s.charAt(0);
```

Because the method subString creates a new String from the index 0 to 2

Comment: 1 character = 1 `char` is not true, for Unicode character beyond plane 0 (Basic Multilingual Plane): http://ideone.com/v8NieH

Answer (score 0):

> If I use line.substring(0,2), I get two chinese character "一二".

So you got two characters. That's what you asked for. The two characters at index 0 and 1.

> But I hope that, the result of line.substring(0,2) is "一".

If you only want one character, ask for one character. The character at index 0. `line.substring(0,1)` for example.

Comment: 1 character = 1 `char` is not true, for Unicode character beyond plane 0 (Basic Multilingual Plane): http://ideone.com/v8NieH

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to decode the file using chinsese encodings, such as GBK, GB2312, etc.
2. Read the line into byte array and then convert that byte array into string using chinese encodings.

   ```
   FileInputStream fileStream=new FileInputStream(New  
   File("sometext.txt"));
   byte[] buf=new byte[12];
   byte[] line=reader.read(buf);
   byte[] byteRange=Arrays.copyOfRange(allBytes,0,2));
   String chineseString=new String(byteRange,Charset.forName("GBK"));
   ```

This way you will only get 1 chinese character. There are only 1  step of conversion from GBK to UTF-8.

Oh, yeah! An improvement from the previous method.

Answer (score -1):

Java use unicode as internal charset, so any char type is unicode.And java.lang.String is consist of chars.

When you get string from reader,the bytes content of file is already translated to chars base on encoding of file.

line.substring(0, 2) result in a new string with fisrt two chars of the *line* to be returned,that's what you already got!

I guess "in my eye the length " mean by you see that in a text editor like UltraEdit,maybe
editor just show the position of bytes in the file

Comment: 1 character = 1 `char` is not true, for Unicode character beyond plane 0 (Basic Multilingual Plane): http://ideone.com/v8NieH